# clearInterval not working as I expect it too

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a demo [which is here](http://jsbin.com/kiput/5/). All you have to do is start typing in the text field, make sure you have the console open. So as you type, you'll instantly see the OMG Saved, and the counter in the console will go nuts.

Now click the button, watching the console you should see something like  `11`  or some other value, but you'll also see the counter reset and **continues** going. I do not want this. I want the counter to stop, I have clicked a button and while the page hasn't refreshed, the counter should stop if I understand [these docs on `setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

the app I am developing which uses code very similar to this, does not refresh as most single page apps don't. So it is imperative that I have control over this `setInterval`.

So my question is:

**How do I reset the counter such that, until I type again in the input box OR if the input box element cannot be found the flash message does not show up, the interval is set back to 0.**

## update

The following is the JavaScript code, which is run on the link provided above.

```
var ObjectClass = {
  
  initialize: function() {
    $('#flash-message').hide();
  },
  
  syncSave: function() {
    $('#content').keypress(function(){
      SomeOtherClass.autoSave = setInterval( function(){
        $('#flash-message').show();
        $('#flash-message').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
      }, 500);
    });
  },
  
  listenForClick: function() {
    $('#click-me').click(function() {
      console.log(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
      clearInterval(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
    });
    
  }
};

var SomeOtherClass = {
  autoSave: null
};

ObjectClass.initialize();
ObjectClass.syncSave();
ObjectClass.listenForClick();
```

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).delay(...).fadeout is not a function`

Comment: Please include the code that is not working in the question itself

Comment: @jgillich That has been fixed. please click the link again.

Comment: The problem is that you are instantiating lots of interval and when you click the button you are killing one only. So if you type ONE character it works fine, thats the problem..

Comment: @AndyJones The whole thing doesn't work, please click the link and try it for your self, after you click the button, the flash message should fade out and that should be that, until I start typing again

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez That does not help me. Do I change the Key Press to something else? I want this thing to trigger when you start typing in the text box.

Comment: @user3379926 yes, I'm aware of that. however, should your jsbin project ever disappear, change, or otherwise become invalid this question becomes worthless. That's why we post the relevant code in the question itself on SO.

Comment: Try using `clearInterval(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);` before this line: `SomeOtherClass.autoSave = setInterval( function(){`

Comment: You sure you don't want [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)?

Comment: @AndyJones The post has been updated.

Comment: @giorgio why would I set the interval when I clearly want to clear it and stop it from counting, upon the button click.

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez Can you post an answer explaining how this would work or why you think it would work?

Comment: @user3379926 I guess I just don't understand what you are doing exactly ;) I was assuming you just want to auto-save on every keypress? (which is quite often actually...). And save it only once each keypress, not every x (milli)seconds after a keypress? Because now, on each press, you are starting a new thread, which keeps on firing until you say it should stop... So imagine what would happen if someone hits a key once, then walks away to read the newspaper or whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put this

```
clearInterval(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
```

before this line:

```
SomeOtherClass.autoSave = setInterval( function(){
```

So that you kill the previous interval and you ahve ONLY ONE interval at the same time

Your code will be:

```
var ObjectClass = {

    initialize: function () {
        $('#flash-message').hide();
    },

    syncSave: function () {
        $('#content').keypress(function () {
            clearInterval(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
            SomeOtherClass.autoSave = setInterval(function () {
                $('#flash-message').show();
                $('#flash-message').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
            }, 500);
        });
    },

    listenForClick: function () {
        $('#click-me').click(function () {
            console.log(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
            clearInterval(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
        });

    }
};

var SomeOtherClass = {
    autoSave: null
};

ObjectClass.initialize();
ObjectClass.syncSave();
ObjectClass.listenForClick();
```

Comment: + 1 but there's no need to unregister with every keypress. OP should just check if it's already set. No need to keep rescheduling it. See http://jsbin.com/cidimuso/1

Comment: `Highlander getSingletonInstance() // “There can be ONLY ONE”`

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is use a timeout instead of an interval, like this:

```
var ObjectClass = {

  initialize: function() {
    $('#flash-message').hide();
  },

  syncSave: function() {
    $('#content').keypress(function(){
      SomeOtherClass.autoSave = setTimeout( function(){
        $('#flash-message').show();
        $('#flash-message').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
      }, 500);
    });
  },

  listenForClick: function() {
    $('#click-me').click(function() {
      console.log(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
      if(typeof SomeOtherClass.autoSave === 'number'){
        clearTimeout(SomeOtherClass.autoSave);
        SomeOtherClass.autoSave = 0;
      }
    });

  }
};

var SomeOtherClass = {
  autoSave: 0
};

ObjectClass.initialize();
ObjectClass.syncSave();
ObjectClass.listenForClick();
```

Comment: NO, the OP wants it to keep flashing until the user clicks the button.  Also, why would you reset `SomeOtherClass.autoSave` to `0` if you are checking ` if(typeof SomeOtherClass.autoSave === 'number')`

Comment: if you run the code above in your JSBin the message will keep flashing as you type in the text box.

Comment: +1 to compensate the downvotes. The OP's intentions are not very clear, but it does make sense to show the warning on every `keypress` instead of on an interval. I don't think a downvote is warranted